# How to use ICD-P520?

Tags: drivers, audacity, soundconverter, sound-recorder

I have a mobile recorder and woukd like to use it or demonstrate it's use with Ubuntu Linux.

**[SONY ICD-P520](https://docs.sony.com/release/specs/ICDP520_specs.pdf)**

Comment: You just plug it into a USB port on your computer..

Comment: This ^^^ and if it doesn't work then it requires proprietary software which, unsurprisingly, exists for older, currently out of support, Windows versions only.

Comment: I'll check in my windowize tablet